# Coldfusion setter method return object?

Tags: unit-testing, coldfusion, tdd, mxunit

I have a coldfusion application which uses Coldspring and FW1 frameworks. I have a cfc `User.cfc`having many properties like name, email etc. These properties are added using  `cfproperty`. When I am writing test cases using mxunit for a function in User.cfc, I got an exception as below

> services.domain.user: The value returned from the setName
>   function is not of type services.domain.user. If the
>   component name is specified as a return type, it is possible that
>   either a definition file for the component cannot be found or is not
>   accessible.

I got this error when I try to mock the setter function using

```
<cfset local.user.$("setName") />
```

So my question is whether cfc setter methods return the same object? I think it should be void

Comment: Is it just for the `name` property or for all other properties?

Comment: I am getting the exception for name only

Answer (score 1):

Your setter should be returning nothing. Setters shouldn't return anything, that's why they're setters and not getters. It looks like the returntype is set to "this", the object. Only the init function should return 'this'.  Check your returntype. 
And you're using ColdSpring AND FW/1? Thats weird.

Comment: I don't have an explicit setter. I am using implicit setters and getters. But why do you think using FW1 and Coldspring weired??

Comment: Newer versions of FW/1 have DI/1 baked in, so ColdSpring becomes redundant.